# How to attach hover to SVG path?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm dynamically drawing svg shapes and I need to attach hover and click listeners to the elements. For some reason I can't get it to work.

I'm creating the svg like this:

```
function svgCreator(){
var objectName = this.name;
$('#container').append('<svg><path class="overlay" id="path_' +objectName +'"d="M5,723,5,716,205,612,226,717" /></svg>')
}
```

later I try to attach hover and click events:

```
function svgHover(){ //svgHover is a method of a generic object
var hotspotObject =this; //hotspotObject is storing the current object as a variable 
this.hotspotSvg.hover( //hotspotSvg is simply $('#path_' +this.name);
    function() { 
    alert('hovering');
    }, 
    function() { 
    $("#outlines").hide();
    }
).click(function() {

alert('You clicked me');
});

};
```

EDIT:
The problem got solved, it wasn't because of the svg at all but because I was attaching the event listener incorrectly. I made the mistake of blaming the svg since that is something totally new I'm trying.

Comment: Are you sure `this.hotspotSvg` is what you think it is?  Because it seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/mEATG/

Comment: You are right! The fault did not lie in the SVG after all but in the way I tried to attach the event.